# Kernel error (Errno 13 Permission denied) in Jupyter Notebook, Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10. I can execute jupyter notebook command. It opens and shows a list of current path directories. I also can create or open a notebook. But when I do it I get Kernel error in the top right corner. After clicking on it this window appears:

> Failed to start the kernel
>
> Unhandled error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 383, in __iter__
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 294, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 294, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 294, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 294, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\lola\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
    with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Lola\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-fd884f4e-8208-4b8e-9db2-c048f869e042.json'
```

The code in my file is not highlighted in different colors and when I run it nothing happens.

I am new to programming, so please try to give advice in simple words, describing each step in detail.

In the past, I've tried to delete Python, install Python in different versions, install Anaconda. In addition, in order to work with tensorflow, I've created a special environment. But this error stays the same. I suspect the problem is a double backslash ("//") in the path, but I have absolutely no idea how to fix this. But perhaps the problem is something else.

Answer (score 13):

Same exact problem here. What worked for me was running the Anaconda Navigator as an Administrator. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: starting jupyter notebook as administrator worked for me

Comment: Works but not the best solution

Answer (score 3):

This problems occurred since the last update of the jupyter_client. 
You can temporarily solve the issue by downgrading to the last version.

```
conda install jupyter_client=5.3.1
```