# Jupyter has problem with kernel. How to fix?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

When i starting work with my jupyter notebook, kernel failed with this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZzsD.png)

all text error

```
BlockquoteTraceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute result = await result 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post type=mtype)) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run value = future.result() 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run value = future.result() 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run value = future.result() 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper yielded = next(result) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel km.start_kernel(**kwargs) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel self.write_connection_file() 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file kernel_name=self.kernel_name 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file with secure_write(fname) as f: 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in enter return next(self.gen) 
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
```

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   `'C:\Users\Zviad\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-2d4299dc-40de-4b99-a7ce-4e3243899961.json'`

Comment: Please format your traceback as code. It is unreadable as a blockquote.

Comment: done. thanks to Pax

Comment: answer find it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174067/kernel-error-errno-13-permission-denied-in-jupyter-notebook-windows-10