# How can I handle kernel errors on my Jupyter notebook (Anaconda)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dependencies, anaconda, kernel

So, the problem I get is

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-c47c0f1d-a7ff-4191-8478-a01d79bfe182.json'
```

this Kernel Error that keeps on popping up when I try to get on Jupyter through anaconda.

I originally had my Jupyter set up and working well on my laptop. I wanted to update the python version of my Anaconda (which I also use for PyCharm), but it led to dependency errors. People on the internet told me to uninstall Anaconda entirely and re-install it with the version of python that I wish to use.

After re-installation, my PyCharm works fine, and python itself seems to work fine on Anaconda Prompt as well, but Jupyter notebook keeps on failing to start the kernel (I tried uninstalling and re-installing Anaconda a multiple times but showed the same result), and now I have no idea what to do.

What could have gone wrong in the re-installation process, could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Does Anaconda have permission to run the kernel? Like if your using mac do chmod Name +x. Or something like that. Hope this will help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel error (Errno 13 Permission denied) in Jupyter Notebook, Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174067/kernel-error-errno-13-permission-denied-in-jupyter-notebook-windows-10)

Comment: Oh, thanks guys! I am using Windows 10. The instruction in the post @Tsyvarev recommended somehow didn't work on mine. But eventually I got a little help from a friend, and now its working fine. I had to do uninstall ipykernel ipython ipython-genutils and install them again.